# argparse and TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror, argparse

I know this one has been asked quite a bit, however trawling through the answers given either:

1. Have not resolved my issue
2. Don't really relate to what I am seeing

I am relatively new to coding in general and this is the first time I have tried to use argparse.

Essentially I am getting the following error from my script:

```
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

I am attempting to write a pretty simple wrapper for Spike Fuzzer, when I have the arguments -p, -v and -s statically set to an integer (not using argparse), the script runs without issue. When I attempt to use the arguments for them, I see the above error.

Please see code below:

```
import argparse, subprocess, os, sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='fuzz.py', 
                                usage='%(prog)s -i 127.0.0.1 -p 21 -d /root/example -v 0 -s 0', 
                                )

parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='[+] Version: BETA')

parser.add_argument('-i', metavar='127.0.0.1',  
                    help="IP Address"
                    )

parser.add_argument('-p', 
                    type=int,
                    default=21,
                    metavar='21',
                    nargs=1, 
                    help="Port (Default 21)",
                    )

parser.add_argument('-d', metavar='/root/example',  
                    help="Spike script directory"
                    )

parser.add_argument('-f', metavar='example.spk', 
                    nargs=1, 
                    help="Spike File"
                    )

parser.add_argument('-v', 
                    type=int,
                    default=0,
                    metavar='0', 
                    nargs=1, 
                    help="SKIPVAR (Default 0)",
                    )

parser.add_argument('-s', 
                    type=int,
                    default=0,
                    metavar='0', 
                    nargs=1, 
                    help="SKIPSTR (Default 0)",
                    )

args = parser.parse_args()

def Directory():
    for file in os.listdir(args.d):
        if file.endswith(".spk"):
            print file
            fuzzer = subprocess.call(['generic_send_tcp', args.i, args.p, file, args.v, args.s])

Directory()
```

If you would like any more information please give me a yell and I will provide what I can.

Cheers,
AJ

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  "...must contain only strings"  Look at the list you are passing to `subprocess.call`; does it consist entirely of strings?

Comment: Side note: You have the meaning of `metavar` wrong. That is supposed to be a ”variable” name, not the default value repeated. For instance 'FILENAME' or 'PATH' for the '-f' option. I would also recommending longer, descriptive names for the options than just those one character names.  The `nargs` arguments don't have any effect because 1 is the default value.  The arguments to `ArgumentParser` are redundant. That information is usually determined by the object itself from `sys.argv` and from the arguments added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to the `argparse` use, the only glaring issue is the use of `nargs=1`.  With that the values will a one element list, not a string.  Leave that off (or use the default `nargs=None`), and values will be strings.

Print `args` after parsing to have a clear idea of what has been parsed.  And if need print selected values, eg. `args.v`.

Print this line:

```
['generic_send_tcp', args.i, args.p, file, args.v, args.s]
```

I'm guessing from the error that `args.p` is `['21']` when it should be simply `'21'`.

The choice of metavar, names etc are just a matter of style, and don't affect the running.

```
In [360]: p=argparse.ArgumentParser()

In [361]: p.add_argument('-f',nargs=1)
Out[361]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f'], dest='f', nargs=1, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

In [362]: p.parse_args(['-f','12'])
Out[362]: Namespace(f=['12'])
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't mark this up due to low reputation (new account). Thanks very much hpaulj, worked a treat.